# PHP eval code and store the result into a variable

Tags: php, templates, eval

I have continued my voyage into creating a extremely simple template engine.
Because I wanted to add logic to my template I eventually got back to the point that I allowed PHP tags into my code which I enabled by evalling the code.

Maybe not the best solution but when looking at the WordPress templates I noticed that the idea itself may not be that bad.

But now there still is one small problem left.
And that is that I want to translate the generated code.

But it has been evalled already. Hence parsed.
I thought of solving this problem by using *ob_get_contents()*.
But this brought one more question and in case of errors it shows a white screen. (memory usage etc.)

Plus it still did not take away the problem of eval that it parsed the contents when evalled.

In short the class logic is:

1. Loading template files
2. Adding the contents
3. Compiling the template
4. Eval the code (but unfortunately also displaying the code)
5. Translate the code so I can translate the code parsed by a PHP script

I would love something like:

```
$code = eval('?>'.$tpl.'<?php');
$code = translate($code);
WriteCache($code);
SetDocumentHeader();
echo $code;
```

Would anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Meta-question: Why create a template engine when there's literally a thousand out there, both some feature-rich and heavy and some very lightweight? Just curious ;)

Comment: @Spoke44 eval() is evil. Yes I know.. But how otherwise implement any decent template logic?

Comment: @Dencker Yes but the point is... Almost all of them are way too bloated. And none of them do exactly what I want. A one file only logical structure template to variable parser. And not a template to PHP file parser. What I want is _relatively simple_ but the execution is incredibly difficult I found out the hard way. :-(

Answer (score -1):

```
$code = eval($tpl);
```

[Check this out.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: I get the feeling that the OP knows how to use `eval`. This doesn't really help him.

Comment: Would be awesome if that would work. But it looks like **eval** executes everything on screen but no avail to an option for just returning the code.